# Form's field doesn't get initialized

Tags: flutter

There id a state class with a form

```
class MyCustomFormState extends State<MyCustomForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String _email, _password;
```

and there is a form where the `initialValue` used

```
TextFormField(
    initialValue: _email,
    validator: (value) {
        if (value.isEmpty) {
            return 'Please enter some text';
        }
        _email = value;
        return null;
    },
),
```

To initialize the email value I use

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _getEmail().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        _email = value;
        print('_email was $_email');
      });
    });
    ...
```

In logs I recive a real email value

> _email was email@email.org

but the form's field doen't get updated, i.e. when the screed rendered, the email field is empty. Why is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the `_getEmail()` appears to be an `async` function. You are calling the the `_getEmail()` function from the `initState()`.

At this point the UI does not wait for the `async` process to complete (`await`), the `build()` method gets called, and the `String _email` is still `null` (not initialised).

The solution would be to update the `TextFormField` with the value of email using `TextEditingController` once the async `_getEmail()` completes.

Your code should look like:

1. Create an object of `TextEditingController` for the email field:

```
TextEditingController emailFieldController = TextEditingController();
```

2. Attach the controller to the email field:

```
TextFormField(
    controller: emailFieldController,
    validator: (value) {
        if (value.isEmpty) {
            return 'Please enter some text';
        }
        _email = value;
        return null;
    },
),
```

3. In your `_getEmail()` function update the email value to the controller:

```
_getEmail().then((value) {
      emailFieldController.text = value;
   });
```

Comment: Using initial value and controller together in the ```TextFormField``` will throw an assertion error. Use either of one not both.

Comment: well, that works, but isn't it a state changing, when we change `controller` value when the form is already rendered? and how does it work without setState() ?

Comment: @rozerro The state of the form gets stored in the `FormState`(`_formKey`), that you have created. So on widget rebuild flutter uses the same state of the form and thus the initialValue is not updated. You can look at how `Keys` work over here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/Key-class.html

Comment: @Vineet You are correct, according to the doc here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextFormField/TextFormField.html . The reason it does not throw an exception for @rozerro is that for him the `String _email` is never initialised, so its always `null`. Good catch. I have updated the answer above